# return type of mouseX in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to figure out the return type of the mouseX function in AS3, but I can't find the documentation on it.  Does anyone know if it returns a Number or an int?

Comment: As prototypical says, it's a Number, and here's the documentation: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#mouseX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a Number

Reason being it needs to be able to be decimal based.